# Fetching list of non-service apps in Android

Tags: android, package, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to pull a list of application running on android. If i don't filter i'm getting a lot of services and long package names.

```
List<String> appList = new ArrayList<>();
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        //get a list of installed apps.
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            if(true){
                Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
                Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
                Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));
                Log.d(TAG, "Name: "+pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo));
                appList.add(pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo).toString());
            }
        }
```

But, if i add a filter for system, its removing basic apps like Phone, messaging, camera etc.

```
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & packageInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM )!=1){
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));
            Log.d(TAG, "Name: "+pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo));
            appList.add(pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo).toString());
        }
    }
```

How can I get a list of all installed application along with system applications?

I'm using android studio 2.3.1 and using the following graddle config:

```
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: "How can I get a list of all installed application along with system applications?" -- that would appear to be your first code fragment. Please explain, **in detail**, what "lot of services and long package names" means. If you are looking for apps with launcher activities, use `queryIntentActivities()` to find launcher activities, then derive the list of apps from there.

Comment: Okay, here's a list of things that show up that i dont want:
charging-related noise suppression
com.android.backupconfirm

Comment: You will need to determine, in technical terms, what it is about those items that make them ones that you do not want. Is it that they do not have launcher icons? Is it that they have "i" in their names? Is it something else?

Comment: Tried with queryIntentActivities(). Seems to work pretty well. Will also ponder upon your last reply. Thanks.